# MongoDB, Java, sort by first array entry

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to sort values after executing a find on my MongoDB by Java API. The result list contains the following entries:

```
{
"_id": "P17-223",
"property": "P17",
"itemid": 223,
"labels": [
  {
    "language": "en",
    "value": "Greenland"
  },
  {
    "language": "es",
    "value": "Groenlandia"
  },
  {
    "language": "de",
    "value": "Grönland"
  }
]
```

}

I want to sort by the first entry of the array *labels*:

```
  DBCursor cursor = getCollection().find(query);
  BasicDBObject orderBy = new BasicDBObject("labels[0].value", 1);
  cursor.sort(orderBy);
```

Cursor values are not sorted by this code. Can you help me?

Comment: It might be a lot easier to sort this in the Java code than on the MongoDB layer. Is that OK for you, or do you insist on sorting it on the database?

Comment: sorting in java is fine, unless you need to query large number of documents

Comment: Have you tried BasicDBObject orderBy = new BasicDBObject("labels.0.value", 1);

Comment: @Mike It's working! Please post this as an answer. I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done, glad it worked for you

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried

```
BasicDBObject orderBy = new BasicDBObject("labels.0.value", 1);
```

It's not obvious, but the MongoDB documentation eludes to it.  Using the $ sign matches the first item, but specifying the array element number seems to work.  If anyone has a better document describing the behavior, please reply with the link.

From the documentation

> Update Documents in an Array

```
The positional $ operator facilitates updates to arrays that contain embedded
documents. Use the positional $ operator to access the fields in the embedded
documents with the dot notation on the $ operator.

db.collection.update( { <query selector> }, { <update operator>: { "array.$.field" : value } } )
```

Documentation is [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Answer (score 5):

I found this question/answer when looking for *How to sort MongoDB (in Meteor) by first item of array*…

I used this to find all documents in the `Schedules` collection which are `active` and then sort ascending by the first day in the `days` array.

```
Schedules.find(
  {
    active: true,
  },
  {
    sort: { 'days.0': 1 },
  },
)
```

A sample `Schedule` collection document with a Monday, Wednesday, Friday schedule looks something like this:

```
{
  _id: 9dh3ld0d7d0d,
  userId: UJD9dKd8edo,
  active: true,
  days: [1, 3, 5],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually "sort" by a specific index of an array within a document in MongoDB.
ct
If you really must do this then you need the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to "extract" the element to sort on.

I know the list form is actually deprecated, so this code is just for demonstration. Acutally define your pipeline as individual variables and feed those as argument to aggregate:

```
    BasicDBList pipeline = new BasicDBList();
    list.add(new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$labels"));
    list.add(new BasicDBObject("$group",
        new BasicDBObject("_id","$_id")
            .append("property", new BasicDBObject("$first","$property"))
            .append("itemid", new BasicDBObject("$first","$itemid"))
            .append("labels", new BasicDBObject("$push","$labels"))
            .append("maxLabel", new BasicDBObject("$max", "$labels.value"))
    ));
    list.add(new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("maxLabel",1)));

    System.out.println(pipeline);
```

That gives you the serialized version which is the JSON form of:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$unwind" : "$labels" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "property": { "$first" : "$property" },
        "itemid": { "$first" : "$itemid" }, 
        "labels": { "$push" : "$labels" },
        "maxLabel": { "$max" : "$labels.value"}
    }}, 
    { "$sort" : { "maxLabel" : 1} }
])
```

Better applied in your code as:

```
collection.aggregate(unwind,group,sort);
```

Where those are individually declared.

Comment: Thanks Neil, puh... complicated ;) Thanks  Philipp, I will try to sort the elements in the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB 3.0 Java Api, you can use [com.mongodb.client.model.Sorts](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Sorts.html)

Exemple use :

```
col.find().sort(Sorts.orderBy(Sorts.descending(fieldname)));
```