# Issue with cosmos DB collection order

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to order my collection using the following query:

```js
db.getCollection('trip').find().sort({'itinerary.0.timestamp': 1})
```

The result is not being correctly sorted, however I exported the full collection to a local mongoDB database and the same query works like a charm. In order to perform that sort in cosmos DB I had to create the index `'itinerary.0.timestamp'`.

data example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6087104ca68f171ce7715448"),
    "tripId" : NumberLong(38533184),
    "itinerary" : [ 
        {
            "transId" : NumberLong(39800097),
            "timestamp" : NumberLong(1619372446291)
        }, 
        {
            "transId" : NumberLong(39800576),
            "timestamp" : NumberLong(1619372446321)
        }, 
    ],
    "results" : [],
    "tripTimeSent" : ISODate("2021-04-29T14:44:53.253Z")
}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks!!

Comment: Pls show the details on your data format, so that we can try to reproduce the same error when test :)

Comment: I've added the data format, maybe this is because there are 10K documents in that collection?
It has to be something related to cosmos DB because using the same 10K documents in a local mongo database the sort is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a new field, itiTimestamp, outside the array containing the value 'itinerary.0.timestamp'. Then just order by itiTimestamp

Answer (score -1):

It's true that you need to create an index for the sort field. Here's [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#indexing-for-mongodb-server-version-36-and-higher) related:

> To apply a sort to a query, you must create an index on the fields
> used in the sort operation.

==========================================

I've tested in my side, after creating wildcard index on itinerary, sort query could be executed but has no luck. I also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24936824)(new BasicDBObject("labels.0.value", 1)) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314964)(db.testCollection.find().sort({"someArray.0": 1})), they all don't work for the date format Op provided.

But when I added a properity `"score":[20,55,80]` in each item in the collection, I found it can be sorted by the first item when sort by score directly.

[image]

I assume that this feature hasn't supported.

Comment: I know I need to create an index, actually I did it. The issue is the results are not being correctly sorted